# Test Design Automation

Tags: manual-testing, test-management

I have downloaded an article from Dzone regarding Test Design Automation. I"m not quite understand what is Test Design Automation.

Please enlighten me on this.

Comment: As you can see, not many people are willing to write high quality answers for questions which are (1) huge/compliated and (2) can be trivially answered by google search and wikipedia. Do some research, do your homework, and ask more specificquestions (and before asking, search for many existing answers).

Answer (score 2):

Test Design Automation is exactly that - **writing your tests in a way that can immediately be used for automation.**

I think you're talking about [this five page article](https://dzone.com/refcardz/test-design-automation) on test design automation. The article goes off on a few (potentially unnecessary) tangents, but it's all in there.

It's best summarised at the beginning of [Chapter 2](https://dzone.com/refcardz/test-design-automation?chapter=2), which says:

> As more and more organizations adopt test-driven, agile development
>   methods, they gravitate towards test design automation — practices and
>   technology that help test teams automatically generate reusable test
>   assets like test cases, test data, and test automation scripts right
>   from clearly defined and complete requirements.

and halfway through [Chapter 5](https://dzone.com/refcardz/test-design-automation?chapter=5):

> Test design automation can help you break the barriers to testing at
>   the speed of agile, while helping you focus on improving quality,
>   collaboration, speed, and efficiency.

The image in Chapter 2 is also quite useful (in context), but re-read the whole page first to make sure you understand the concept... otherwise it doesn't make much sense:

[image: Test Design Automation example]

Answer (score 1):

[This is an excellent example of how Spotify use Model Based Testing](http://www.cs.tut.fi/tapahtumat/testaus12/kalvot/Karl_ta.pdf)

This is the closest to Test Design Automation I could think of, you define the rules and overall design and let the code do the rest